# In Multi Tenancy with separate databases for each - How to create Centralised Service for User Login?

Tags: database, api, multi-tenant

I am revamping an existing product, it has multi tenancy with separate database for each tenant. Now we need a single API to authenticate user without the information of tenant, as that is common login portal. What is the best approach for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

There are below given approaches

**Case 1** Use a shared collection of tables that contain some data about the tenant's, their users etc.

> In this case you will have a scalable admin service (can be a microservice) that talks to this database and can authenticate the users, tenants

**Case 2** If the application is on large corporates and uses user's email address in the company domain's (as like in AD), steps are below.

- you get the email address,
- identify the domain
- choose the tenant based on the identified domain
- resolve the connection string based on the tenant
- identify the database based on the identified tenant
- Route to the DB and do the authentication

**Case 3** when there are user's that can work in multiple tenants (like financial auditors), the idea of having a global users table is a good option. I get myself authenticated, then choose my tenant based on my mapping. Get into the tenant, do the tasks.

You can read more on this in my blog post https://dsaravanan.wordpress.com/2021/05/02/user-authentication-schemes-in-a-multi-tenant-saas-application/

Comment: Thanks let me go through the article.